# the search bar in Xcode 5 crashes when i type something

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, uisearchbar

the search bar in Xcode 4.5.1 crashes when i type something, and it worked just fine when i was using Xcode 4.4
please help

i used this code which was an answer for another question, and it worked just fine when i was using Xcode 4/4, until i updated it to 4.5.1

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar{

//Perform the JSON query.

[self searchCoordinatesForAddress:[theSearchBar text]];

//Hide the keyboard.
[theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];}

-(void) searchCoordinatesForAddress:(NSString *)inAddress{

NSMutableString *urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=json",inAddress];

//Replace Spaces with a '+' character.
[urlString setString:[urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

//Setup and start an async download.
//Note that we should test for reachability!.
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

NSArray *placemark  = [results objectForKey:@"Placemark"];
NSArray *coordinates = [[placemark objectAtIndex:0] valueForKeyPath:@"Point.coordinates"];

double longitude = [[coordinates objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
double latitude = [[coordinates objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];



[self zoomMapAndCenterAtLatitude:latitude andLongitude:longitude];}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to edit this code/errors using the mark-down, its hard to read without being formatted.

Comment: My question is *how did OP manage to acquire Xcode 5*?

Comment: i don't know, what i know for sure is that my app worked perfectly in Xcode 4.

Comment: sorry i meant Xcode 4.5 not 5 and Xcode 4.4 not 4

Comment: please show us your errorlog, so we have more information about what went wrong. This way it's impossible to help you.

Comment: please edit the title, now we have xcode 5.